# Linq OrderByDescending, null first

Tags: c#, linq

I have a field in my database that holds a DateTime?. I would like to sort the results so that the NULLs show up at the top, then descending by DateTime, e.g.,

```
null
null
2012-04-01
2012-01-01
2011-09-04
```

The reason is that I am looking at expiration dates, though some entries do not expire.

Comment: I found this to be a better solution if it's not a datetime http://stackoverflow.com/a/15247558/59508

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can return [DateTime.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx) instead of `null` from the ordering expression, so rows with `null` dates are sorted first:

```
yourData.OrderByDescending(row => row.dateTimeField ?? DateTime.MaxValue);
```

Comment: awesome solution, i had to do the inverse, but works great

Answer (score 36):

I find the most straightforward approach to be:

```
data.OrderBy(Function(o) o.myDate IsNot Nothing).ThenByDescending(Function(o) o.myDate)
```

in C# I think...

```
data.OrderBy(o => o.myDate != null).ThenByDescending(o => o.myDate)
```

This will also work with LINQ to SQL. I'm not sure if `if(nullable, value)` will successfully translate to SQL.

Comment: Does `.OrderBy(o => o.myDate != null)` not remove the nulls from the set entirely?

Comment: In case anyone else has the same question, `.OrderBy(o => o.myDate != null)` does not remove the nulls from the set. It only sorts the set.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var nulls = table.Where(x => x.NullableDateTimeField == null);
var notNulls = table.Where(x => x.NullableDateTimeField != null);

var result = nulls.Concat(notNulls.OrderByDescending(x => x.NullableDateTimeField));
```

It's more "obviously correct" than "likely to be super-efficient", but it's at least a starting point.

Comment: You're missing any ordering clause.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [David Oesterreich's blog:](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121060553/http://www.davidoesterreich.com/blog/linq-sort-by-nulls-last/)

```
var queryResult =
orderedProducts from enumerableProducts
order by orderedProducts.ProductName,
orderedProducts.Price != null ? 1 : 0 descending,
orderedProducts.Price
select orderedProducts;
```

Answer (score 0):

like the accepted version above but with syntax for c# v6

```
tickets.OrderByDescending(x => x?.Erstellt ?? DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: This doesn't help unless you're expecting nulls within "tickets", which seems like a separate issue entirely. This will also break if any of the date values are ahead of now, which is literally anything scheduled in the future.