# Linq OrderByDescending with two nullable date columns

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a table with two nullable datetime columns, ETA and ETD.  One always has a value.  I want to order the table by date.  So for example if ETA is null use ETD to order.  If ETD is null use the ETA, if both are not null use ETA (as it's always first).

I have this:

```
var route = db.RouteJourney.Where(j => j.JourneyId == id).OrderByDescending(j => j.ETA ?? j.ETD);
```

I've also tried this (which is the same):

```
var route = db.RouteJourney.Where(j => j.JourneyId == id).OrderByDescending(j => j.ETA.HasValue ? j.ETA : j.ETD);
```

Am I missing something?  My small brain says that if ETA is null use ETD and then order it but it doesn't give the right result.

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT

I am getting with this:

If RouteJourney is [Name, RouteId (Key), JourneyId, ETA, ETD]

and values are:

[Stop A, 1, 1, null, 10/03/13], [Stop B, 4, 1, 12/03/13, 13/03/13], [Stop C, 2 , 1, 14/03/13, null], [Stop D, 3, 1, 16/03/13, null]

Ordered like this:

Stop C
Stop B
Stop A
Stop D

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a anonymous type

```
var route = 
    db.RouteJourney
    .Where(j => j.JourneyId == id)
    .OrderByDescending(item =>
        (new { DT = item.ETA.HasValue ? item.ETA : item.ETD }).DT);
```

Or pretier in QES:

```
var route =
    from item in db.RouteJourney
    where item.JourneyId == id
    order by
        (new { DT = item.ETA.HasValue ? item.ETA : item.ETD }).DT
    descending
    select item;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but it's still producing the same order.  I'm confused.

Comment: Please ignore me...I am stupid.  had a 2012 in the data structure which I didn't see.  Thanks for the help.